# acrescentar ao id +1 toda vez que for feito um novo cadastro

Tags: c

acrescentar "+1" toda vez que faço um cadastro

o programa da um id constante e não muda com um novo cadasreo

```
void cadastroCliente(){
    system("cls");
    FILE *arquivo_cliente;
    CLIENTE clt;
    arquivo_cliente = fopen("cliente.dat","ab");
    if(arquivo_cliente ==NULL){
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
    }else{



        do{

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o nome: ");
            gets(clt.nome);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o CPF: ");
            gets(clt.cpf);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o email: ");
            gets(clt.email);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o Telefone: ");
            gets(clt.telefone);

            fwrite(&clt,sizeof(CLIENTE),1,arquivo_cliente);
            printf("\nDeseja continuar(s/n)");

        }while(getch() =='s');
        fclose(arquivo_cliente);
    }
}

int acrescentarIdCliente(FILE *arquivo_cliente){
    unsigned long ultimID, id;
    CLIENTE clt;
    clt.id =0;
    ultimID=1;
    fseek(arquivo_cliente,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(fread(&clt,sizeof(CLIENTE),1,arquivo_cliente)==1){

          if(clt.id>=ultimID){
             id++;
             ultimID=id;
          }
          else
            return id;
       }
    return id;

}
´´´
```

Comment: Para ficar genérico você pode primeiro ler todo o arquivo e pegar o maior valor já cadastrado, aí é só somar 1. Dependendo de como você manipula as eventuais alterações e exclusões no arquivo é possível otimizar este processo.

Comment: Seu programa não está bom. Entenda que id é local à função e a cada chamada começa a existir de novo. Estude escopo de variáveis. Se quer manter o valor de `id` deve declarar como `static`. Escreva em torno dos dados: é muito mais simples: crie uma estrutura Cliente. E uma estrutura Cadastro que agrupa.... clientes, claro. Não use fflush() para entrada. NUNCA use gets(). Faça o simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que **apenas se tratando de ler e incrementar o `id`, o problema está no fato de estar usando o ponteiro ao arquivo que foi aberto para escrita dos bytes**:

Função `cadastroCliente`:

```
FILE* arquivo_cliente = fopen("cliente.dat","ab");
```

Como abriu o arquivo para escrita, é necessário que abra um novo buffer de leitura dentro da função `acrescentarIdCliente`:

```
FILE* arquivo_cliente = fopen("cliente.dat","rb");
```

O que também pode ser feito é abrir um buffer para **leitura e escrita (append)** e continuar passando o ponteiro como argumento para a função:

```
FILE* arquivo_cliente = fopen("cliente.dat","ab+");
```

Creio que [este link com referências em português](https://terminalroot.com.br/2014/12/linguagem-c-utilizando-as-funcoes-fopen.html) possa ajudar.